# Find the min and max value of column 3 and print whole row

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

I have huuuge sets of data consisting of 3 columns. I'd like to be able to find max and min values in the third column (there is mix of zeros and then negative values, so I want to find max negative and min negative value) and then print that particular row. How can I do that?

example input:

```
-6.4 -3.6 -0.00
-6.4 -3.5 -0.00
-6.4 -3.5 -0.00
-6.4 -3.5 -0.00
.
.
.
-2.4 -1.6 -14.50
-2.4 -1.5 -14.49
-2.4 -1.5 -14.49
-2.4 -1.5 -14.49
.
.
.
-5.4 -2.6 -4.52
-5.4 -2.6 -4.53
-5.4 -2.6 -4.50
-5.4 -2.6 -0.00
-5.4 -2.6 -0.00
```

output:
min:     -2.4 -1.6 -14.50

max:    -5.4 -2.6 -4.50

Comment: Give an example of the data and the expected output.

Comment: I've edited, hope it's clear now!

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match your data. If the values in column three are all negative then the maximum value should be zero.

Comment: Unfortunately there are negative zeros, but those data are meaningless. What I wrote is what I need to get.

Comment: Zero is neither positive nor negative. I understand what you need but it's just stated wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already accepted an answer but here's an easier way:

```
egrep -v "0.00|^\." file.txt | awk 'NR==1 {print "min:",$0} END{print"max:",$0}'
```

Output:

```
min: -2.4 -1.6 -14.50
max: -5.4 -2.6 -4.50
```

-As you don't want the zeroes even though they're actually the largest number, the `egrep -v` command prints all lines except those containing 0.00 and beginning with a "."

-After the above, the lines are already in order from smallest to largest. `awk` then prints the first line with "min:" prepended and the last line with "max:" prepended.

If the values in that column happen to not be in order, you can pipe `sort -k3` (assuming it's the third column you want to sort) after the `egrep` command and then pipe it into the `awk` command after it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this in Python. If your data is whitespace-separated, it will be something as simple as:

```
minVal = None
maxVal = None
with open('file') as f:
  for line in f:
    # default: split on whitespace.
    third = int(line.split()[2])
    if not minVal:
      # initialize the values
      minVal = third
      maxVal = third
    else:
      minVal = min(third, minVal)
      maxVal = max(third, maxVal)

print("min", minVal)
print("max", maxVal)
```

**EDIT**: given that you want the entire row, you should instead store `minRow` and `maxRow`. It the past, when I have had to do something like this, I have used a custom min/max function. Both take a `key` argument to specify a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with awk :

```
awk -v 'f=1' '
  NF==3 {
    min = min < $3 ? min : $3
    if ( min != oldmin ) {
      a = $0
      oldmin = min
      }
    if ( $3 < 0 ) {
      if ( f ) {
        max = min
        f = 0
      }
      max = max > $3 ? max : $3
    }
    if ( max != oldmax ) {
      oldmax = max
      b = $0
      }
    }
  END {
    print "min : " a RS "max : " b
    }
' infile
```